# How to forward access-control-allow-origin header from a Web App to a Front Door?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-front-door

I currently have a web app running in containers with the access-control-allow-origin header correctly configured on it. However, when I check the front door in front of this web app, the same header has the option '*' -- accepting all types of requests, differently from the configured one.

How do I get the front door to propagate this web app header?

Comment: You can configure Rules Engine in Azure Front Door and set appropriate access-control-allow-origin header in request.
https://blog.hametbenoit.info/2020/05/13/azure-front-door-service-now-allows-you-to-define-rules-preview/#.YCpvbmgzaM8
Does this answer your question?

Comment: @AndriyBilous, this configuration it's what I ended up going with but it's not working; still giving me '*' in my allow origin instead of the configured one :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the official document about this: [Azure Front Door Rule Set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/standard-premium/troubleshoot-cross-origin-resources#azure-front-door-rule-set)

> On Azure Front Door, you can create a rule in the Azure Front Door
> Rules Set to check the Origin header on the request. If it's a valid
> origin, your rule will set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header with
> the correct value. In this case, the Access-Control-Allow-Origin
> header from the file's origin server is ignored and the AFD's rules
> engine completely manages the allowed CORS origins.
> [image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work in my scenario. I'm currently exchanging emails with the Azure folks to solve this.

Comment: This is the correct answer indeed, the problem was that I had a trailing backslash and forgot to purge the cache. The guys at MS helped figure it out this. Thanks, Doris.

Comment: Happy to hear that you solve this. @LucasAlmeidaCarotta

Answer (score 1):

[Doris lv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13586071/doris-lv)'s previous answer is correct but I would also like to point out some things:

- Be careful not to add the slash (/) at the end of the URL -- *I had that added that's why didn't work*:

[image]

- After creating the rule, go to **Front Door designer (FDD)** and link this new rule with some of the routing rules available

[image]

- Also in FDD, click on the **Purge** button clean the previous cache and load the new configurations

[image]

Another important thing is that I had to do this configuration due to [HDCL AppScan](https://cloud.appscan.com/AsoCUI/serviceui/home) saying that the **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** header was too permissive; that being said, the scan pointed that the Java Scripts files had this problem which they didn't, only the CSS and TFF files had this header. A closer look at the scan report pointed out that what's was going on is that the **Vary** header had the value *Origin* in it, making the scan report a Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) issue. To fix this just add a new rule in the Rule engine configuration removing this header just like shown:

[image]

After this, the scan didn't report any more issues